# Уникальное имя фотографий и видеозаписей

Tags: php, база-данных

Почему в ВК, YouTube и других сайтах, уникальные имена даются вида набора букв. Не легче уникальное имя давать цифрами например 1-32 (id-НомерФотоИлиВидеоОтЭтогоПользователя) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даются различные варианты хешей.

**Если давать в открытом id, то можно легко просканировать все фотографии, видео со всеми вытекающими последствиями...**

Comment: это ещё связано с cdn